# Method collision between JAXB and rest of the Application

Tags: java, jaxb, pojo

I am converting an existing POJO to be an JAXB compliant. Everything works fine except for one of the getter method of the pojo where I need an additional logic specific to rendering XML. However, this getter is already called somewhere within the application and I cannot modify this method's behavior.
How do I normally deal with such method name collisions? Is there a way I create a separate method just for JAXB purpose adn mark the currentmethod as XMlTransient?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, exactly what you said would work. Make the one method @XmlTransient, then write another method and make it an @XmlElement(name="whatever element name").

Comment: I am now getting an error related to the change: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 2 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
Property element1(which JAXb derives from my new getter method) is present but not specified in @XmlType.propOrder

Comment: just realized that I had to use the getter's derived property as the property name in the propOrder list.

Answer (score 2):

You can put XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD) on the class. Then the JAXB annotations will be picked up from the field names, and not the method names. For example:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class MyType {
    @XmlElement String f1;
    @XmlElement Integer f2;

    // JAXB doesn't care about these:
    public String getF1() {return f1;}
    public String getF2() {return f2;}
    public void setF1(String f1) {this.f1 = f1;}
    public void setF2(Integer f2) {this.f2 = f2;}
}
```

Comment: I only wanted thw field behavior for field f1 and not the rest of the properties. Is there a way to define XmlAccessType.FIELD at the field level rather than class level?

Comment: Thanks Blaise. Yes, I ended up doing what you suggested.